# The date picker only works after the first line, why doesn't it work on the first line?

Tags: jquery

The Datepicker does not work in the first row in the modal table, it works in the second row

```js
var satirsayi = 0;

$('#satirekle').click(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker({
    autoHide: true,
    zIndex: 999998,
    format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
  })
  
  ++satirsayi;
  
  $('.odemeplanitablosu tbody').append(
    '<tr>' +
      '<td>' + satirsayi + '</td>' +
      '<td><input type="text" name="vade" id="vade' + satirsayi + '" class="form-control"/></td>' +
      '<td><input class="edit-item-date form-control vvtarih' + satirsayi + '" data-toggle="datepicker" name="vadetarih" id="edit_due_date' + satirsayi + '" autocomplete="off"></td>' +
      '<td><input type="text" name="vadegun" id="vadegun' + satirsayi + '" class="form-control"/></td>' +
      '<td><input type="text" name="vadeoran" id="vadeoran' + satirsayi + '" class="form-control"/></td>' +
      '<td><input type="text" name="vadeborc" id="vadeborc' + satirsayi + '" class="form-control"/></td>' +
      '<td><input type="text" name="vadealacak" id="vadealacak' + satirsayi + '" class="form-control"/></td>' +
      '<td><input type="text"  class="genelkalan" name="vadekalan" id="vadekalan' + satirsayi + '" class="form-control" disabled/></td>' +
    '</tr>'
  );
```

Comment: You need to first append the html table and after that you can initialize the datepicker.

Comment: Before your .datepicker line, add some *basic* debugging:  `console.log($('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').length)` - first time it will be zero, 2nd time 1, 3rd time 2 etc.   Use `$("<tr>..").appendTo('.odemeplanitablosu tbody').find(".edit-item-date").datepicker({...` to add the datepicker to the newly added item only.